# Bit manipulation C source in Java

Tags: java, c, bit-manipulation

I try to calculate the checksum of a Sega Genesis rom file in Java. For this i want to port a code snipped from C into Java:

```
static uint16 getchecksum(uint8 *rom, int length)
{
  int i;
  uint16 checksum = 0;

  for (i = 0; i < length; i += 2)
  {
    checksum += ((rom[i] << 8) + rom[i + 1]);
  }

  return checksum;
}
```

I understand what the code does. It sums all 16bit numbers (combined from two 8 bit ones). But what i didn't understand is what's happening with the overflow of the uint16 and how this transfers to Java code?

Edit:
This code seems to work, thanks:

```
int calculatedChecksum = 0;
int bufferi1=0;
int bufferi2=0;
bs = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(this.file));

bufferi1 = bs.read();
bufferi2 = bs.read();
while(bufferi1 != -1 && bufferi2 != -1){
    calculatedChecksum += (bufferi1*256 + bufferi2);
    calculatedChecksum = calculatedChecksum % 0x10000;
    bufferi1 = bs.read();
    bufferi2 = bs.read();
}
```

Comment: You can take a larger integral type and reduce modulo `0x10000` in each loop round.

Comment: This code is exactly the same in Java. Just use a `unsigned byte[]` for the `uint8_t` pointer and a `unsigned short` for the checksum. Everything else is the same.

Comment: @JasonCoco: Java doesn't have an `unsigned short` type.

Comment: @MarkByers So true... Java doesn't really have unsigned types at all, my bad. I haven't worked with it in ages.

Comment: I tried something with modulo but it didn't seem to work (code in my original post). Ok, sorry i forgot to skip to the correct position in my input stream. It works now. Thatks to Kerrek SB. When you post your comemnt as answer i will accept it.

Comment: @JasonCoco Not exactly.  Java does have the char type, which is an unsigned 16-bit number.  Otherwise, though, Java is indeed missing unsigned integer types.

Comment: @Johni the behavior of that function is undefined for `length` not a multiple of `2`.

Comment: @KerrekSB it doesn't need to be done each round.

Comment: @veer: True... it depends on how large the numbers get, eh?

Comment: You actually *could* use a short here. Signedness does not affect addition. You'd just have to be careful to interpret the result in an unsigned way (eg don't accidentally sign extend it).

Comment: @KerrekSB it doesn't need to be done every round in any case, since you're taking the modulo with an other power of two, so it's OK to let it overflow modulo a bigger power of two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want addition modulo 2<sup>16</sup>, which you can simply spell out manually:

```
checksum = (checksum + ((rom[i] << 8) + rom[i + 1])) % 0x10000;
//                                                   ^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, the overflow is lost.
A more correct approach (imho) is to use uint32 for summation, and then you have the sum in the lower 16 bits, and the overflow in the upper 16 bits.

Answer (score 1):

```
static int checksum(final InputStream in) throws IOException {
  short v = 0;
  int c;
  while ((c = in.read()) >= 0) {
    v += (c << 8) | in.read();
  }
  return v & 0xffff;
}
```

This should work equivalently; by using `& 0xffff`, we get to treat the value in `v` as if it were unsigned the entire time, since arithmetic overflow is identical w.r.t. bits.

Comment: Ok, this & 0xffff is interesting. Have you more informations about that?

Comment: @Johni it treats all 16 bits of a `short` as an `int`.

Comment: Yes, buts what causes this behavior? Since a biswise "and" doesn't change the data itself.

Comment: @Johni taking the bitwise AND with 2^k-1 is the same as doing a modulo with 2^k. It's necessary here because otherwise the implicit cast to int would sign-extend, but `v` is supposed to be treated as unsigned.